# KO Cannot find template with ID

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-templating

I am trying to bind a template to my view. But I keep getting template with ID error.

Template: `<script type="text/html" id="Template">

        //some html markup
</script>`

View : `<div data-bind="template: {name: 'Template'}"></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works!

```js
ko.applyBindings({});
```

```html
<script src="//knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="Template">
  some Markup
</script>

<div data-bind="template: {name: 'Template'}"></div>
```

Comment: I have knockout 3.1.0.min. I tried the same approach but I am getting the same error. Where do we applyBindings ? May be I am not doing it correct.

Comment: You must call it after your document is loaded, so either at the end of `<body>`, or using something like `window.onload`.